# Parsing JSON from a (sub)string

Tags: json, parsing

Supposed I have a string that contains JSON:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Then I can easily parse this using the `JSON.parse` function.

Now supposed the string has some additional prefix, such as:

```
blah: {"foo":"bar"}
```

Then simply using `JSON.parse` does not work, of course. What I'd need to do is to extract a substring and then run the function. Now supposed I do not know the content or the length of the prefix (i.e., I don't know whether it finishes with a colon and a space, or whether it is always six characters long, or …): What is the best way to parse the contained JSON?

The most obvious way would probably be to just find the index of the first `{`, but this won't work if the string itself contains a `{`.

Is there a better, i.e. more reliable, way to do this?

Comment: i think there is no such intelligence provided to us ( or i don't know) ... so that u can remove the unwanted/unpredicted string and find the valid json to parse... the other thing you can do is... search for the substring index of {" and "} ... suppose int indexOfStartOfJson=indexof( {" ); int indexOfEndOfJson=indexof( "} ); and now substring your string ... i.e String validJson=substring(indexOfStartOfJson,indexOfEndOfJson);

Comment: Try indexOf("{"), lastIndexOf("}"), and substring...?

Comment: @BNK This is what I already said I could do, but I was looking for better options ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `replace` to remove the prefix, something like:

```js
test = 'blah: {"foo":"bar"}';
test = test.replace(/^.*?{/, "{");
alert(test);
```

The above regex works with:

```
blah: {"foo":"bar"}
blah{"foo":"bar"}
blah:{"foo":"bar"}
blah {"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but as said I do not know whether there is always a space in the end, hence this check won't work for all cases.

Comment: Just make the space optional, `?`. I'll update the regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know *anything* about the prefix, I guess you might have to remove one character at a time and try parsing the remainder as JSON. As soon as you succeed, you'll have found the starting point.

If the parsing fails a SyntaxError will be thrown which you'll obviously have to handle.

Comment: This works, but probably is quite slow… but anyway, thanks for suggesting this!

Comment: Yeah, definitely a last resort, both style wise and performance wise :)